# Datagrid rowClick function to use a value other than the id of the record for custom pathing

Tags: react-admin

The rowClick-prop for Datagrid is a welcome addition to react-admin.

Is it possible to use any other field of the record than the id for the custom path function? I have a list of function results that have a SourceId that refers to a function I'd like to link to.

I've been playing around but can't seem to find how to access the other fields of the record.

Answer (score 0):

`rowClick` accepts a function that takes three values `(id, basePath, record)` so you will have to use the third, `record`.